# delphi2010 Traversal record of rtti

Tags: delphi, rtti

```
type
 myrec = record
 id:dWord;
 name:array[0..31] of  WideChar;
 three:dword;
 count:dword;
 ShuXing:Single;
 ShuXing2:dword;
 ShuXing3:dWORD;

  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  mystr:TMemoryStream;
  nowmyrec:myrec;

implementation
 USES Rtti;
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);


var
  rttiContext: TRttiContext;
  rttiType: TRttiType;
  fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
  item: myrec;
  i:word;
begin
mystr:=TMemoryStream.Create;
mystr.LoadFromFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.exename)+'1.data');
mystr.Position:=20;
mystr.readbuffer(nowmyRec,88);




 rttiType := rttiContext.GetType(TypeInfo(myRec));
  fields := rttiType.GetFields;
   for i := low(fields) to high(fields) do
   begin
Memo1.Lines.Add(fields[i].GetValue(@nowmyRec).ToString );


   end;

end;

end.
```

the myrec.name is Chinese characters,the length of  myrec.name is 64 byte , i can not read the myrec.name to memo, please help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Delphi 2010, and I found a couple of issues with your code. First of all, I couldn't get the RTTI methods to work with the inline declaration of the character array. I changed it to:

```
type
  TCharArray = array[0..31] of WideChar;
  TRec = record
    id:dWord;
    name:TCharArray;
  end;
```

If you declare the array inline, the way you had done, the call to `GetValue` raise an AV. That's probably fixed in XE, or quite possibly I'm using RTTI incorrectly.

Secondly, you need special treatment for arrays as opposed to scalar values:

```
procedure Main;
var
  i, j: Integer;
  rec: TRec;
  rttiContext: TRttiContext;
  rttiType: TRttiType;
  fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
  val: TValue;
  s: string;
begin
  rec.id := 1;
  rec.name := 'Hello Stack Overflow';

  rttiType := rttiContext.GetType(TypeInfo(TRec));
  fields := rttiType.GetFields;
  for i := low(fields) to high(fields) do begin
    val := fields[i].GetValue(@rec);
    if val.IsArray then begin
      s := '';
      for j := 0 to val.GetArrayLength-1 do begin
        s := s+val.GetArrayElement(j).ToString;
      end;
      Writeln(s);
    end else begin
      Writeln(val.ToString);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Output:

```
1
Hello Stack Overflow
```

This obviously isn't production code, but it should at least get you back on the road!

P.S. This is the first time I've looked at the new RTTI functionality. It looks pretty nifty!

Comment: i am reading a  hex data ,it must be use a tstream !!   " rec.name := 'Hello Stack Overflow': can not suit on me

Comment: @baba Your problem is with the RTTI not the stream code. Since I don't have your binary input data to hand I populated the record with my own data just to prove that the RTTI code worked. Feel free to populate your own record however you like.

Comment: @baba Why don't you make the change to the definition of your record as I suggest. That will stop the AV in the second call to GetValue. Then replace your code that calls `fields[i].GetValue(@nowmyRec).ToString` with my version that adds `IsArray`. Then it will work.

Comment: @baba Thanks for the accept. I trust you are content now. By the way, you have enough reputation to vote now!!  ;-)